# Issue on Listing Sub Product Categories In Woocommerce

Tags: categories, terms

Using Following code I am able to list all top level Categories on Woocommerce Product Categories

```
$args = array(
    'number'     => $number,
    'orderby'    => 'title',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    'parent' => 0,
    'include'    => $ids
);
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
$count = count($product_categories);
if ( $count > 0 ){
    foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
        echo '<h4><a href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">' . $product_category->name . '</a></h4>';

    }
}
```

Which are:

Contact Lenses
 Designer Eyeglasses
 Designer
    Sunglasses
 Eyeglass Lenses

Now I need To List All Sub Categories Just For `Designer Sunglasses` in separate page I tried to pass the `designer-sunglasses` slug instead of `'product_cat'` in the `get_terms()` but it didn't return any thing. Can you please let me know how to do this and list all sub categories for each of them in separate page?

> Update

by ID:

```
$args = array(
    'number'     => $number,
    'orderby'    => 'title',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    'parent' => 1702,
    'include'    => $ids
);
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
$count = count($product_categories);
if ( $count > 0 ){
    foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
        echo '<h4><a href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">' . $product_category->name . '</a></h4>';

    }
}
```

by Name:

```
$args = array(
    'number'     => $number,
    'orderby'    => 'title',
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    'parent' => "designer-sunglasses",
    'include'    => $ids
);
$product_categories = get_terms( 'product_cat', $args );
$count = count($product_categories);
if ( $count > 0 ){
    foreach ( $product_categories as $product_category ) {
        echo '<h4><a href="' . get_term_link( $product_category ) . '">' . $product_category->name . '</a></h4>';

    }
}
```

Comment: Note: Third party plug-in questions are generally [off topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), but this has actually nothing to do with the plug-in you use.

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)« and/or »[Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 0):

To get children with [`get_terms()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms) you have two options. You can either use the argument `parent`, which will only get *direct* children, so only one level down; or you use `child_of`, which gets *all* descendants, meaning until last level down. Both `parent` and `child_of` need an integer as value, which would in both cases be the parents ID.

Basic code example:

```
$taxonomies = array(
    'product_cat'
);
$args = array(
    // in case you haven't assigned the terms to products
    'hide_empty' => 0,
    // replace with the parent ID you need
    'parent'     => 10
);
$product_categories = get_terms(
    $taxonomies,
    $args
);
```

Comment: Hi ialocin Thanks for reply but I tried the using of `parent` but it is not returning any thing

Comment: Can you please take a look at update  which I loaded the two way I tried to get the result. but as I said they are not working

Comment: Like I said `parent` needs to be an integer, so by name won't work. What about the `'include' => $ids` part, are you sure it's correct there. Aside from that I only can tell you, `product_cat` is just a regular WordPress taxonomy, so getting children like described should work, unless something else isn't working. @Behseini

Comment: I've added a basic code example, this has been working on every single installation I had running so far. Provided that you have at least one parent and one related child term and setup the correct parent ID. Work your way from there - good luck! @Behseini